# Semisimple algebraic group defined over a number field

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Below, a linear algebraic group stands for a Zariski-closed subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_d(\mathbb{C})$ for $d\geq 1$.

I say that a linear algebraic group $G$ is *realizable* over a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$ if there is $n\geq1$ and Zariski-closed subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, where $H$ is defined by a set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$, such that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as algebraic groups.

I am only starting to learn about algebraic groups, but would like to know the following while I'm learning:

> Is every semisimple linear algebraic group realizable over $\mathbb{Q}$? If not, is it realizable over a number field?

Comment: Why is the number field relevant in your definition of realizable?

Comment: @CoherentSheaf: I meant to write that $H$ is defined over $F$! Edited now. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, so every semisimple algebraic group over $\Bbb C$ is split. By the work of Chevalley, the classification of split reductive (e.g. split semisimple algebraic groups) is the same over any field and this classification is compatible with base change. Consequently, every split reductive group over a field with characteristic $0$ is defined over $\Bbb Q$, this implies that they're realizable in the sense of the question.

Comment: @LukasHeger: Thank you!

Comment: @LukasHeger: If $G$ is a semisimple Zariski-closed subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_d(\mathbb{C})$ defined over a number field $F$, then by your comment there's $n\geq 1$ and a Zariski-closed subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as algebraic groups. Can we take the regular functions defining the isomorphisms (in both directions) to have coefficients in $F$?

Comment: @LukasHeger I believe your last claim is false, although counterexamples are not so easy to find. If you take $F$ to be a number field, and $S$ a finite set of places of $F$ with $\#S$ even, then there is a quaternion algebra $D / F$ ramified precisely at the places in $S$. If $G$ is the group of norm 1 elements of $D$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $SL_2$ over $\mathbf{C}$, and of course $SL_2$ is definable over $\mathbf{Q}$; but we cannot find an isomorphism between $G$ and $SL_2$ over $F$ (unless $S$ is empty).

Comment: (There is an extensive theory using Galois cohomology groups to classify the isomorphism classes of algebraic groups over $F$ in a given isomorphism class over $\overline{F}$; the book by Platonov and Rapinchuk is a good reference for this.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler thanks for the correction! You're of course correct, I've deleted the incorrect comment.